# Why isn't the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ completely reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

In the book *Representation Theory A First Course* the authors write on page 6 that

> **Corollary 1.6** Any representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations.

> This property is called complete reducibility or semisimplicity. [...] The additive group $\mathbb{R}$ does not have this property: the representation $a \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1 & a\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ leaves the $x$ axis fixed, but there is no complementary subspace.

Could someone enlighten me why there isn't a complementary subspace to this representation? It is because the image of the representation does not contain the zero matrix?

Comment: It follows from the Jordan normal form theorem. Also a proof that it is indecomposable is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484809/indecomposable-but-not-irreducible-representation-and-direct-sums?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Not really, it doesn't. It's just an elementary calculation, no deep theorems required. Now, if you wanted to classify all finite-dimensional representations of $\mathbf R$, then maybe Jordan's theorem would be relevant, but this is just a fixed one.

Comment: @tomasz Jordan normal form is no deep theorem. It is just a tool available from linear algebra a long time before any representation theory. I don't see why we shouldn't use it (and it is indeed used in many duplicates here).

Comment: OK, "deep" may not be the right phrasing. Perhaps I should have said "nontrivial" instead. Anyway,  these matrices are very concrete. How would Jordan's theorem help with (or simplify) the argument?