# Indecomposable but not irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions

I am recently learning representation theory and come across with the example that the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ acts on $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$\begin{pmatrix}
1&x\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1+xv_2\\
v_2\end{pmatrix}$

I know that this representation is reducible because it has a proper subspace $W=\{(w,0)^T|w\in \mathbb{R}\}$ which the group acts on. But it is indecomposable:
[Indecomposable but not irreducible representation and direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484809/indecomposable-but-not-irreducible-representation-and-direct-sums)

I understand the proof in the above link but I would like to ask isn't the representation decomposable because we have the decomposition $V\cong W \oplus V/W$ and both $W$ and $V/W$ are non trivial?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: $V$ is not isomorphic to $W\oplus V/W$. Why did you think it would be?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry I thought it is true that for every finite dimensional vector space $$ with $$ a vector subspace, we have $V\cong U \oplus V/U$

Comment: Only isomorphic as vector spaces, here we discuss isomorphic as *representations*. The group $\Bbb{R}$ acts trivially on the direct sum $W\oplus V/W$. That is, each $x\in\Bbb{R}$ acts via the identity mapping, but that is not the case with $x$ acting on $V$. Hence they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much.